# Reach question for Dancing Blade Parry Stance

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

When in the Stance Dancing Blade Parry from the Tome of Battle, it says "your reach increases by 5 ft."

Does this mean I can only attack enemies with the extended reach or do I still have the option to attack an adjacent enemy within 5 ft. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are still able to attack adjacent creatures.

The rules that say you can't attack adjacent only appear for **[reach weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#reachWeapons)**:

> A reach weapon is a melee weapon that allows its wielder to strike at targets that aren’t adjacent to him or her [...] 10 feet away, but not a creature in an adjacent square

The stance is not making your weapon a reach weapon, it's simply giving you more reach, which has **[different rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/movementPositionAndDistance.htm#largeHugeGargantuanandColossalCreatures)**:

> Unlike when someone uses a reach weapon, a creature with greater than normal natural reach (more than 5 feet) **still threatens squares adjacent** to it.